Prove every Cauchy sequence in R is bounded
Here's my attempt to prove every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded, I would like to see if there are any flaws in it.
Proof: Let ${(x_n)}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Now let's suppose ${(x_n)}$ is unbounded and try to find a contradiction.
Let $\epsilon=1$ Since ${(x_n)}$ is Cauchy $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N, |{x_n}-{x_N}|<1\implies {x_n}<{x_N}+1$
Now we select $M=max({x_1},{x_2}...{x_N})+1$. By our assumption that ${x_n}$ is unbounded there exists a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that ${x_k}>M$. Notice that $k$ cannot be any integer less than or equal to $N$ because then ${x_k}\leq M$. Thus $k > N$.
Therefore ${x_k}<{x_N}+1 < M$. A contradiction.
Note: This only shows $({x_n})$ is bounded above but showing $({x_n})$ is bounded below is similar.

This appears essentially OK.  However, strictly $| x_n - x_N| < 1 \implies |x_n| < |x_N| + 1$ (you have left out the modulus signs).  Then $|x_n| < \max(|x_1|, |x_2|, \cdots , |x_{N}|)+1$.  There is then no need to argue by contradiction and you have covered $x_n$ positive or negative in one step.

You can also argue that  every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is convergent and then show that convergent sequences are bounded.

A nice version is at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662618/confusion-regarding-the-proof-that-every-cauchy-sequence-is-bounded?rq=1
